# mapbox change highlight 3d building

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I don't think there's a solution for this but maybe i'm wrong or it'll be possible in future.

I'm trying to highlight a building in mapbox (3d or 2d) given the exact address or GPS coordinates.

Is it even possible to uniquely identify buildings in mapbox?

I couldn't find anything in their [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) and hacking it in seems difficult since everything is painted on a single canvas.
[image: html snippet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's feasible, even a part of a building. Anything represented in Mapbox as a building, is based in 1 or more features. For that you need to query the features and then decide what is the attribute you will use to filter only some features to differentiate the behavior.

Check this out, it's a fiddle on [how to change color and pointer on mouse over](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/L3omh45v/41/), where I have added a filter for only one feature id among all of the buildings in NYC, that will become red changing its state ('hover ; true') and the mouse pointer is changed to `map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'pointer'`.

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```js
        let mapConfig = {
          NYC: {
            origin: [-74.044514, 40.689259, 39],
            center: [-74.0137, 40.70346, 0],
            zoom: 16.2,
            pitch: 60,
            bearing: 35
          }
        }

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT HERE YOUR TOKEN';
        let point = mapConfig.NYC;
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
          center: point.center,
          zoom: point.zoom,
          pitch: point.pitch,
          bearing: point.bearing,
          container: 'map',
          antialias: true,
          hash: true
        });

        map.on('style.load', function() {

          if (map.getSource('composite')) {
            map.addLayer({
              'id': '3d-buildings',
              'source': 'composite',
              'source-layer': 'building',
              'type': 'fill-extrusion',
              'minzoom': 14,
              'paint': {
                'fill-extrusion-color': [
                  'case',
                  ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
                  '#ff0000',
                  '#ddd'
                ],
                'fill-extrusion-height': ["number", ["get", "height"], 5],
                'fill-extrusion-base': ["number", ["get", "min_height"], 0],
                'fill-extrusion-opacity': 1
              }
            }, 'road-label');
          }

          let fHover;

          map.on('click', function(e) {
            var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
              layers: ['3d-buildings']
            });
            console.log(features[0].id);
          })

          map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
              layers: ['3d-buildings']
            });
            //we will change pointer and color for 42455719
            if (features[0] && features[0].id == 42455719) {
              mouseover(features[0]);
            } else {
              mouseout();
            }

          });

          map.on('mouseout', function(e) {
            mouseout();
          });

          function mouseout() {
            if (!fHover) return;
            map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'default';
            map.setFeatureState({
              source: fHover.source,
              sourceLayer: fHover.sourceLayer,
              id: fHover.id
            }, {
              hover: false
            });

          }

          function mouseover(feature) {
            fHover = feature;
            map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'pointer';

            map.setFeatureState({
              source: fHover.source,
              sourceLayer: fHover.sourceLayer,
              id: fHover.id
            }, {
              hover: true
            });
          }

        });
```

Comment: Nice! Do you have any idea how we would get the features based on an address or gps location? Inside feature the only property i could think of is _x and _y but those seem to be the same for the building right next to it.

Comment: For an address/coords, you will need to use probably [Mapbox Geocoder](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/) and/or [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geocoding/) directly, depending your needs in the UI side. That will give you a feature that you can use to highlight as shown

Comment: Thank you for your help. The Geocoding API yields a list of features, however none of them match the id retrieved on the mouseclick. I'm guessing Geocoding API does not return the features from the 3D map but rather those displayed on the normal map?

Comment: The 3D features are created from the source 'composite' source-layer = 'building' with the attribute extrude = 'true', so if you have the feature id you can easily query the source 'composite' to find it. Check the default [example from mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/)

Comment: The features i get from the geocoding api look like this `address.10641720978437020` whereas the feature id's of the 3d buildings are only numbers like `44900725`. How can i get the id of the 3d buildings from the geocoding api?

Comment: @F.H. supposedly its the Mapbox [Navigation SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/navigation) that facilitates this